# Is there a way to use IParsable.Parse() without the "provider" parameter?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I'm trying to make a piece of code that parses a string to an object of type `T where T : IParsable<T>`. Here's my code right now:

```cs
public static T differentParse<T>(string str) where T : IParsable<T>
    => T.Parse(str);
```

The compiler keeps telling me to add an `IFormatProvider? provider` parameter to the `T.Parse` method even though I don't want to. Is there any way to parse like this without an `IFormatProvider? provider` parameter?

Comment: No, all the methods in `IParsable<TSelf>` accept an `IFormatProvider`, so you need to supply one. What culture *do* you want to parse the value as? (Imagine a value of "04/03/2023" for example, parse as a DateTime - you'd get a different result in US English to UK English. Would you expect to get April 3rd or March 4th?) Any reason you don't want to supply `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`? (I *suspect* if you pass a null argument, it will use the current culture.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Didn't want one because didn't know how, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JonSkeet for helping me find this solution!

```cs
public static T differentParse<T>(string str) where T : IParsable<T>
    => T.Parse(str, null);
```

Comment: Next question will be "why my fx double doesn't parse on client machine" but code works on mine"... Same as date double format may vary depends on culture in some countries we are using coma and in other dot as decimal separator... You should stick to one format and use it independently of current culture... That's why `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is better choice...

Comment: @Selvin I mean... I don't think it matters for my usecase as I will be reading from user input anyway and they'll type the input in their own culture so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Matto58 That's an inaccurate statement! Jon Skeet would **never** pass `null` as an `IFormatProvider`.